# Reduce spacing GridView

Tags: android, gridview, spacing

I'm try to create a GridView where the values are as close as possible to each other.
Now the content is spread out all over the screen.

[image: GridView layout]

How can I reduce the spacing between the cells of the GridView?
Using the setVerticalSpacing() method didn't work.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".LevelSpelen" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1">

</GridView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/gridView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
    android:text="" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="78dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The spacing is defined in 2 ways: the spacing between cells, and the spacing within a cell

In your `GridView` definitions add

```
android:verticalSpacing="8dp"
android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
```

or smaller and add `android:numColumns="auto_fit"` to make sure that you can fit as many items as possible in each row.

In the `GridView Item` layout, make sure that you make the cell as small or as big as you want

Comment: I've added those 2 properties, but that doesn't change anything. And I specify the numColumns in my code. But where can I change the spacing of the items?

Comment: Do you use `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1` when you set up the adapter?

Comment: No, this is the code ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.activity_level_spelen,R.id.textView1,inhoud);

Comment: I'm not sure how ArrayAdapter lays out the textview in terms of spacing, but if you set the number of columns in code then it will probably space out the cells automatically, try to change 'android:layout_width="fill_parent"' in the GridView definition to `wrap_content` or a specific value